# Rails :method=>:patch doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So, I have this form declaration:

```
<%= form_for 'students_list', {:url => update_students_list_stream_url(@stream), :method=>:patch}  do |students_list_form| %>
```

Just as described in API docs, but this leads me to error:

```
No route matches [POST] "/streams/26/edit-students-list"
```

So it still tries to post, even though my HTML input has:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch" />
```

From Rails guide:

> Rails works around this issue by emulating other methods over POST
>   with a hidden input named "_method", which is set to reflect the
>   desired method:

I'm quite confused

Comment: If I get you right, you are trying to make an update to the student list stream, is this correct?

Comment: Rails uses the [`Rack::MethodOverride` middleware](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/857641dab255dbec490fead1d3a0f1ff999b2137/lib/rack/method_override.rb) which processes the request before it is passed to the routes.  `Rack::MethodOverride` should be picking up on the `_method` param and i'm also a bit puzzled on why its not working. I would suggest trying to send the request with cURL or Postman to troubleshoot as you are eliminating any browser related bugs or anything related to the form.

Comment: Note that the Rails unobtrustive javascript driver also does some trickery to send native PATCH/PUT/DELETE requests and this could also be part of the problem.

Answer (score 5):

I was looking for an answer on why rails loaded method patch as post in the rendered form.
If you ended up here looking for that like I did, this is the answer you are looking for:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/46699512/5750078

From https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#how-do-forms-with-patch-put-or-delete-methods-work-questionmark:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Rails use `Rack::MethodOverride` middleware that tweaks the HTTP methods PUT/PATCH to POST for supporting old browsers.

This can happen on Rails API application to unload the middleware for performance. In some cases where you want to call a casual PUT/PATCH request using `form_with` tag in the views, simply add

```
# config/application.rb

config.middleware.insert_after Rack::Runtime, Rack::MethodOverride
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll be better doing this:

```
<%= form_for @stream do |student_form_list| %>
```

---

If you've set up your routes using the standard [`resources` directive](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resources-on-the-web), you'll have the following routes:

[image]

Of these routes, the `update` path *should* just be `students_list_stream_path` -- *not* the `update_students_list_stream_path` you have now.

If you've set up the `form_for` to use the correct object, it will automatically set the path & method for `update`.

Comment: I found out, that :method declaration for some reason doesn't work (except post and get), if you form builder have any hidden field. When I removed `students_list_form.hidden_field`, it started working and sends PATCH request. Not sure if it's some Rails bug or what to do if I need hidden field.