# Rails 4 not changing post method to patch

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, url-routing, forms, http-post

I am trying to submit a form, but if I just put `form_for @classroom` I get a "No route matches [POST]" error.

Now with the code posted below, I get the wrong url in the form. If I change the url manually in the browser it goes through, and I guess I could do that via javascript, but... why... is... this... happening..?

Until yesterday everything was working fine. I even tried rolling back to the things I changed but I can't seem to track what is going wrong.

### routes.rb

```
patch 'classrooms/:id/update' => "classrooms#update", as: :update_classroom
resources :classrooms, except: :update
```

### form from rails end

```
<%= form_for(update_classroom_path(@classroom), method: "patch") do |class_f| %>
```

### form in browser

```
<form action="/classrooms/23/edit" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
<input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch">
<input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="******">
```

### rake routes

```
        absences POST   /absences(.:format)                   absences#create
                 POST   /classrooms/:id/getAbsences(.:format) classrooms#getAbsences
update_classroom PATCH  /classrooms/:id/update(.:format)      classrooms#update
      classrooms GET    /classrooms(.:format)                 classrooms#index
                 POST   /classrooms(.:format)                 classrooms#create
   new_classroom GET    /classrooms/new(.:format)             classrooms#new
  edit_classroom GET    /classrooms/:id/edit(.:format)        classrooms#edit
       classroom GET    /classrooms/:id(.:format)             classrooms#show
                 DELETE /classrooms/:id(.:format)             classrooms#destroy
            root GET    /                                     pages#start
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to answer your question from title, I think your form method is "PATCH" indeed.  Refer to the guide http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html about how rails makes a patch form.

> The Rails framework encourages RESTful design of your applications, which means you'll be making a lot of "PATCH" and "DELETE" requests (besides "GET" and "POST"). However, most browsers don't support methods other than "GET" and "POST" when it comes to submitting forms.
>
> Rails works around this issue by emulating other methods over POST with a hidden input named "_method", which is set to reflect the desired method:

Answer (score 3):

After some more trial and error, I realised I had left some plain input tags in a deeper nested level of the form (instead of going with the normal fields_for and separate builders for each level). I guess that somehow screwed up the relations and affected the method of the parent form.

That was such a mind blending mess up.

Edit: Andylee's answer is right. What I and Jeremy mention was probably the actual issue going on and not what was originally assumed to be the problem (as mentioned in the title).

Answer (score 3):

To add a bit of specificity, to Tashow's answer above (which set me on the right track), I had some hidden fields that look'd like this, in a nested form.:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag("Classroom[classroom_teachers_attributes][]", nil) %>
<%= hidden_field_tag("Classroom[classroom_teachers_attributes][]", '') %>
```

Once I got rid of these, everything began working properly again. (There still remained similar-looking `<input>` tags generated by `fields_for`, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

`form_for` takes an object as first argument, and its usually better to keep the REST-like way of rails handling the `update` method.

The `action` of you html form displays "/classrooms/23/edit" so yes it won't work.

```
form_for(@classroom, url: update_classroom_path(@classroom), method: "patch")
```

Comment: I am aware of that. I would expect that only using @classroom, should automatically route to the patch route, but it doesn't seem to be the case. Your suggestion gives me 'No route matches [POST] /classrooms/23/update' as well :/

Comment: using only @classroom automatically route to the original patch route, but not your

Comment: It wasn't working with the original patch route either. That's why I made a custom route in the first place. I found out it was probably caused because of some hardcoded input fields I had in the form. You can read the answer bellow. Thanks for your input!